# UWP button Pressed and Release event handlers

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

New to UWP development.  I am stumped because I want to display a button that while pressed will jog a motor forward.  When the button is Released the motor is stopped.

```
<Button  Grid.Row="2" Content="Jog Forwards" Height="120" Width="120" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,80,0" Click="Jog_forward_click" ClickMode="Press"/>
```

This creates the jogging forward Pressed event handler.  Evidently, you cannot have more than 1 "ClickMode" in the button definition, so it won't let me add the Release event handler.
Am I approaching this the wrong way?
How can i have one button with multiple event handlers (old verbage)?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purposes, use PointerPressed and PointerReleased. Also, Binding to IsPressed would be another way to handle this.

```
<Button PointerPressed="OnStartMotor" PointerReleased="OnStopMotor">
    Start Me Daddy!
</Button>
```